# Targeting the last-child in a CSS Nested Pseudo-selector structure

Tags: css-selectors

**Goal:** Target and stylize only the last 'root' child of a particular html element type, in a structure where sibling root-children element types have nested children of the same type.

**Problem:** All nested children get stylized outside the root-children as well.

**Example:** Given the following chunk of a larger structure, I would like to only target the 'GOLD' span, which will always be the last child of type span in of the parent div.

```css
div span:last-child {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div>0

  <span>1
      <span>2
        <span>3
        </span>
      </span>
  </span>

  <br/>

  <span>a
      <span>b
        <span>c
        </span>
      </span>
  </span>

  <span>GOLD
  </span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `>` after `div`:

```css
div>span:last-child {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div>0

  <span>1
      <span>2
        <span>3
        </span>
  </span>
  </span>

  <br/>

  <span>a
      <span>b
        <span>c
        </span>
  </span>
  </span>

  <span>GOLD
  </span>

</div>
```